# Gradle during its execution phase, adding and executing tasks dynamically

Tags: gradle

I have the requirement to create and execute tasks during Gradle's execution phase.

Currently, during my build task I determine and create multiple tasks which I add to the taskContainer, using:

`tasks.add([name: "$taskName", type: "$taskType"], {...})`

and then after all the tasks are added I execute them sequentially, using:

`tasks["$taskName"].execute()`

On the first execution I get the following error:

> The task artifact state cache (.../.gradle/1.5/taskArtifacts) has not been locked.

**What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to dynamically add tasks during execution?**

Comment: Why are you adding them during execution, and not during the configuration phase of the build?

Comment: @HieryNomus Doing this in the configuration stage sends my spider-senses tingling as I would need to pull down the resources before I have knowledge of how many targets to build. As I understand, calling `gradle tasks` would then pull down the build resources, not ideal or expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tasks and task dependencies must be declared in the configuration phase. They can't be added in the execution phase. Also, calling `task.execute()` isn't supported (and will lead to problems). A task can *depend* on other tasks, but it cannot *call* them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do create tasks at configuration phase.

```
afterEvaluate{
    project.getTasks().create("name", org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec,
        { task -> defineRunTask project, task, application })
}
```

This will allow you to create a task dinamically at the end of configuration phase.

In order to execute the tasks, you simply add those task that depends on this list of tasks, like:

```
afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks.forEach{ task -> {
        project.tasks.compileJava.dependsOn task
    }
}
```